# while inserting i get the following error : "Error preparing INSERT INTO licenselog(timelog) VALUES('2015-11-16 14:21:07')"

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

i want to insert the current time and date into database but the statements are not getting prepared. platform : iOS, sqlite3 and objective C.

### The following is the database schema

```
CREATE TABLE licenselog(lid integer not null primary key,timelog varchar(30) not null);
```

### The following is my database functions:

```
-(int) addLog:(NSString *)logDate
{

[self openDB];
NSString *insertString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO licenselog(timelog) VALUES('%@')",logDate];
NSLog(@"Insert Query=%@",insertString1);
const char* query = [insertString1 UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *query_stmt = NULL;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &query_stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Error preparing %@", insertString1);
    return 0;
}
if(sqlite3_step(query_stmt)!= SQLITE_DONE)
{NSLog(@"Error running insert %s",query);
    return 0;
}
[self closeDB];
return 1;
}
```

i have also used the following function(for a different table) in the same database class but it works fine.

```
-(int) addLicense:(NSString*)licenseName
            expiryDate:(NSString*)expiryDate
{
[self openDB];
NSString *insertString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO license_details(license_name,expiray_date) VALUES('%@','%@')",licenseName,expiryDate];
NSLog(@"Insert Query=%@",insertString);
const char* query = [insertString UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *query_stmt = NULL;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &query_stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
       NSLog(@"Error preparing %@", insertString);
        return 0;
}
if(sqlite3_step(query_stmt)!= SQLITE_DONE)
    {
      NSLog(@"Error running insert %s",query);
      return 0;
    }
 [self closeDB];
 return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you create a table `licenselog` but try to insert into a table `license_log`.

Comment: sorry for that. while copying i did it by mistake. however i have rechecked and edited it.
still it is giving me the same problem. i m not sure why.
i have debug the code both the functions. they all have the similar values 
but when they reach this statement
     if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &query_stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 

they give a different output (one enters the loop whereas the other doesnt)

Comment: try to put this `NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database))` into the block that also logs the error...

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. dont mind for the silly questions as i m very new to iOS.
And yes i found the answer. the table was not getting created in the database for some reason.
when first creating the database i had done it through the terminal and created the .sqlite3 file to create a 1st table.
later i used the terminal again to do add new table but wasnt getting created even though it showed up on terminal it dint work while runng app.
I so changed the query on the function to create a table. now its getting created and working fine. can u explain why?? Thanks a lot for helping me :) appreciate it